# Audio on TouchesEnded

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, audio, playsound

On TouchesEnded I want to do two things: 
1) return the view to its original position - this works fine.
2) I want to play an audio sound if the touch ended on the YES vies and a different sound for the NO views.

How can I do this?

At this moment my sound for NO will play for every touch ended - and this is not good.

I am new to this so please explain the basics :) my current code below.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    yesletter1.frame = keepYesLetter1Place;
    yesletter2.frame = keepYesLetter2Place;
    yesletter3.frame = keepYesLetter3Place;
    yesletter4.frame = keepYesLetter4Place;
    notletter1.frame = keepNoLetter1Place; 
    notletter2.frame = keepNoLetter2Place;
    notletter3.frame = keepNoLetter3Place;
    notletter4.frame = keepNoLetter4Place;   

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"no"ofType:@"wav"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                               initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

    [theAudio play];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue not the way i wanted but thing work now.
I have 2 different sounds for some objects one sound and the other another sound.
What i did is added a flag for each object and did if(flag1 == 0 || flag2 == 0 ect...) play sound 1 else play sound 2.
in another method which does something else i played with the flags.

I am sure there is a better solution for this :) but things work now.